# PopupMenu onitemclick not working android

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have created a Popup Menu inside Recycler View like below. I changed the style of Popup Menu to set the text colour using ContextThemWrapper but, since then the Popup Menu item click listener is not working. Please note that I am using androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper package for ContextTheme Wrapper

```
         Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(ctx1, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
        
          final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, viewHolder.overflow_bt);
          MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
          final Menu pop = popup.getMenu();
        
        
          popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener
               (new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) {
        
        
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                       case R.id.delete:
                        //handle menu1 click
                         Delete_post(post_key);
                         break;
        
                       case R.id.edit:
        
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx1, EditPost.class);
                            tartActivity(intent);
        
                            break;
        
              }
        
        
             return false;
            }
            });
           popup.show();
        
        }
   });
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
       
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myLargePopupMenuTextAppearanceColor</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/mySmallPopupMenuTextAppearanceColor</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blackPrimary</item>


    </style>

    <style name="mySmallPopupMenuTextAppearanceColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blackPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myLargePopupMenuTextAppearanceColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blackPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) is always returning false,your popup menu onitemclick wont work.You need to return true in order to make your popup menu itemclick work.
Do this:

```
         @Override
         public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) {
    
    
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                   case R.id.delete:
                    //handle menu1 click
                     Delete_post(post_key);
                     return true;
    
                   case R.id.edit:
    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx1, EditPost.class);
                        tartActivity(intent);
    
                        return true;
                
                 default: return false;
    
         }
        }
        });
       popup.show();
```

I think the problem is you havent inflated your popup menu:
add this line below your MenuInflater line :

```
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_id);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It didn't work. I replaced `break;` with `return true;` as you suggested but not working.

Comment: have u added default: return false ?

Comment: You havent inflated your menu.